# In Princes of the Apocalypse, is there a way to permanently get Tinderstrike?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, published-adventures

In the hardcover of Princes of the Apocalypse, is there a way to get Tinderstrike permanently without

> sacrificing it to the portal?
>
>  We have killed the holder and he dropped Tinderstrike. Based on what other people have told us, we have to sacrifice it at some point.

Is there a way to get it permanently? I've seen people wielding it outside the module and some in trading groups.

Comment: If you're talking about Adventurer's League play (which the "trading groups" reference implies), you should make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't sacrifice it?  It's not like you have to lose it for any reason-- heck you could abandon the entire quest as soon as you found it if you wanted; this is an RPG, not a computer game.  Your choices and the consequences thereof are your own.